# How to use Spring Specification to filter through many to many realtionship?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, filter, spring-data-jpa

I decided to create filters in my application with **Spring Specification.** Everything was going well but I don't know to do filter `User events`. Which filter events by user login.

My entities look like this:

```java
@Entity
public class EventEntity {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="events")
    private Set<UserEntity> participants = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
    
    @Id
    private String login;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_events",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_login"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    )
    private Set<EventEntity> events = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I read many subjects on stack but still don't know to how to implement my filter logic and filter beginning looks like this:

```java
    private Specification<EventEntity> findUserEvent(String login) {
        return (root, cq, cb) -> {
            if(login.isEmpty()) return cb.conjunction();
    
            Root<EventEntity> event = cq.from(EventEntity.class);
            Join<EventEntity, UserEntity> users = event.join(EventEntity_.PARTICIPANTS)
            return builder.equals ???
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ummm... `cb.equal(UserEntity_.login, login)`? Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: I tried cb.equal(users.get(UserEntity_.LOGIN), login) but that gave me 0 results in test. Are you sure that should work, because maybe I did wrong relationships or save...? And this is correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the same models and entered a few sample data.

You can see this data as follows:

[image]

Let's write in your specification code as follows:

```java
private Specification<EventEntity> findUserEvent(String login) {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> {
        if (login.isEmpty()) return cb.conjunction();
        Join<EventEntity, UserEntity> join = root.join("participants");
        return cb.equal(join.get("login"), login);
    };
}
```

When we use the **specification code** to get `user-c` user's events, 2 events will return.

```java
List<EventEntity> events = eventEntityRepository
        .findAll(findUserEvent("user-c"));
System.out.println(events.size());
```

If something different is happening, **first check that you have records in your database and if the metadata definitions contain correct values.**

Comment: Thanks for such involvement. Your solution does not work in my situation but it seems to be correct so I will try to find what can be wrong on my side and I let you know if i solve it

Comment: First check your database tabled, if there is data, check the metamodel definitions.

Comment: Ok i figured it out. Your solution is correct. I've got problem with cascading and then with saving my entities with repository to test it. My "connection" table was empty that's why i had 0 results (because jpa couldn't make join). Again thanks for help